# Automated ROT13 spoiler comments

Tags: script, greasemonkey, comments

## About

Spoilers get used pretty heavily on Puzzling.SE, and people have taken to using rot13 in comments (and chat) since there's no official spoiler mark-up outside of questions/answers. That's annoying, but this script will make your life easier.

[image: rot13 at work]

## Features

1. Add rot13 spoilers to comments

   - Whenever you're typing a comment, surround any text you want to be spoilered with `rot13(<text to be spoilered>)`
   - A ROT13 link will appear to the right (between the Add Comment button and the help link)
   - Clicking ROT13 will convert all `rot13(...)` text in your comment (obviously clicking again will convert back)
   - Post your comment as usual
2. Automatically convert existing rot13 spoilers in comments

   - Any comments containing spoilers in the format `rot13(<spoilered text>)` will automatically get highlighted
   - Hover the highlight to see the unspoilered text in the tooltip

     - **Edit (v1.5)**: "tooltip" is now an overlayed panel
   - <del>Click the link to see the unspoilered text in an alert popup</del>
   - **Edit (v1.5)**: Click the highlight to pin the tooltip panel in place, click again to hide (allows copy/paste, etc)
   - **Edit (v1.5)**: Handles nested parentheses in rot strings (thanks @GentlePurpleRain)
   - **Edit (v1.5)**: Preserves (most) formatting in and around rot strings (including links)
   - **Edit (v1.5)**: Supports fallback mode for non-"standard" rot strings (eg. rot13[...], (ROT13)..., Rot13:..., etc) which rots the entire comment
3. **Edit (v1.2)**: Both the above features now also work in SE chat rooms

<sub>(I left the encoding process fairly manual so as not to be potentially annoying when writing/editing comments)</sub>

#### Download/Source

[View script source](https://bitbucket.org/alconja/user-scripts/src/master/rot13-comments.user.js) / [Install / download](https://bitbucket.org/alconja/user-scripts/raw/master/rot13-comments.user.js)

#### Platform

Tested with Greasemonkey in Firefox and with Tampermonkey in Chrome.

Comment: Wonderful! Though I wonder why not use a simple delimiter (like MathJax does) instead of having to type out `rot13(...)`. How about something like, for example, `!!...!!` or `>>...<<`, etc.

Comment: @GaurangTandon - two reasons: 1) so people who haven't seen it before (and don't have the script) have some chance of recognising what it is, and 2) because `rot13(...)` is already the defacto standard used on puzzling.se.

Comment: This makes dealing with all those rot13(Fcbvyre!) comments on [puzzling.se] much easier, but I prefer to have the converted text replace the original instead of popping up in an `alert()`, so I replaced line # 82 with ``var link = `<a href="#" onclick="this.innerHTML = 'rot13(${text.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\").replace(/'/g, "\\'")})';return false;" title="${text}" >${found[0]}</a>`;`` Personally it still isn't perfect for me, so I may make more changes in the future, but I thought you and/or others might want to do this too, as the `alert()` really broke the flow of things for me.

Comment: @3D1T0R - you may be interested in the latest version which renders much nicer (no more alerts!).

Comment: Links for test: [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82350/) and [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/116394/82896)